# PHP: Is type-checking return values a good practice to compensate PHP's lack of generics?

Tags: php, generics, typechecking, type-hinting

**Note**: To prevent downvotes because *good practice* might be opinion based - you can also rephrase the question as: *What are the downsides of type-checking return values to compensate PHP's lack of generics?* (I didn't use that as it implies that there *are* downsides).

### Question

Coming from a Java/C# world, PHP's loose type handling has always been somewhat annoying. It got better when type-hinting for input parameters was introduced but I'm still missing [generics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generic_programming) and type-hinting for return values.

I find myself to occasionaly work around that by explicitly checking types within my code - which feels somewhat wrong since the language itself could handle it for me - and I would like to push these questions to the community:

- **Is type-checking return values a good practice to compensate PHP's lack of generics?**
- **Is there a better/more standard way to do this?**
- **Are genericts currently discussed for future implementation in PHP?**

### Example

To get a better idea why that is problematic, consider the following example:

Assume we are building a framework to transform input data in some other ouput data. Examples:

Transform a string representing an XML document into a DomDocument into another string by selecting the title of said DomDocument by an xpath expression.

```
(string) $xml =[TransformToDomDocument]=> (DomDocument) $doc =[TransformToString]=> (string) $title
```

Now let's assume the input is not a string containing XML but Json (but holds otherwise the same data). We'd now want to transform the Json input into a Json object and selet the title by using a [JsonPath](http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/) expression.

```
(string) $jsonString =[TransformToJson]=> (Json) $jsonObject =[TransformToString]=> (string) $title
```

(*Note*: The second example should clarify that the whole framework should be really flexible.)

The transformation is performed by using a chain of adapter objects that handle the conversion from input to ouput:

```
interface AdapterInterface{

  /**
    * Transform some input data into something else.
    * @param mixed $data
    * @return mixed
   */
  public function transform($data);

  /**
    * Set the Adapter that is used to preprocess the $data before calling $this->transform($data)
    * @param AdapterInterface $adapter
   */
  public function setPredecessorAdapter(AdapterInterface $adapter);

}

class XmlToDomDocumentAdapter implements AdapterInterface{

  private $predecessor;

  /**
    * Transform an xml string into a DOMDocument.
    * @param mixed $data
    * @return DomDocument
   */
  public function transform($data){

    if($this->predecessor !== null){
      $data = $this->predecessor->transform($data); 
      // At this point, we just have to "trust" that the predecessor returns a (string)
    }
    $doc = new DomDocument();
    $doc->loadXml($data);
    return $doc;
  }

}

class DomDocumentToStringAdapter implements AdapterInterface{

  private $xpathExpression;

  private $predecessor;

  /**
    * Transform a DomDocument into a string.
    * @param mixed $data
    * @return string
   */
  public function transform($data){

    if($this->predecessor !== null){
      $data = $this->predecessor->transform($data); 
      // At this point, we just have to "trust" that the predecessor returns a (DOMDocument)
    }
    $xpath = new DOMXpath($data);
    $nodes = $xapth->query($this->xpathExpression);
    if($nodes->length > 0){
        throw new UnexpectedValueException("Xpath didn't match");
    }
    $result = $nodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
    return $result;
  }

}
```

Usage:

```
$input = "..."
$xmlToDom = new XmlToDomDocumentAdapater();
$domToString = DomDocumentToStringAdapter();
$domToString->setPredecessorAdapter($xmlToDom);
$output = $domToString->transform($input);
```

The problematic part occurs when an adapter relies on it's predecessor to return the right input.

```
    if($this->predecessor !== null){
      $data = $this->predecessor->transform($data); 
      // At this point, we just have to "trust" that the predecessor returns a (DOMDocument)
    }
```

In C# I'd solve this problems by using [generics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379564%28v=vs.80%29.aspx):

```
interface AdapterInterface{

  /**
    * Tranform some input data into something else.
    * @param mixed $data
    * @return T
   */
  public function T transform<T>(object data);

}

/* using it */
//...

    if(this.predecessor !== null){
      data = this.predecessor.transform<string>(data); 
      // we now know for sure that the data is of type 'string'
    }
//...
```

Since generics are not supported in PHP, I'm asking myself if it's a good practice to add a type check after every call to `transform($data)` like this:

```
    if($this->predecessor !== null){
      $data = $this->predecessor->transform($data); 
      if(!is_string($data){
        throw new UnexpectedValueException("data is not a string!");
      }
      // we now know for sure that the data is of type 'string'
    }
```

### My current workaround

Im currently using multiple interfaces to define the output of the `transform` method like this:

```
interface ToStringAdapterInterface extends AdapterInterface{

  /**
    * Transform some input data into something else.
    * @param mixed $data
    * @return string <<< define expected output
   */
  public function transform($data);
}

interface ToDomDocumentAdapterInterface extends AdapterInterface{

  /**
    * Transform some input data into something else.
    * @param mixed $data
    * @return DOMDocument<<< define expected output
   */
  public function transform($data);
}
```

In each transformer I make sure to accept only the suitable interface as predecessor:

```
class DomDocumentToStringAdapter implements ToStringAdapterInterface {

  private $xpathExpression;

  private $predecessor;

  public function __construct(ToDomDocumentAdapterInterface $predecessor){
      $this->predecessor = $predecessor;
  }
  // ...
}
```

Comment: Good idea or not, practically no one does it.

Comment: If you're using type hinting or simply type validation on *input* parameters to all your functions and objects, that problem is mostly nonexistent anyway. Errors may propagate one step further because they're type checked on the next function call instead of at function return time, but in practice that's hardly a problem. If you absolutely insist on such checks, I'd add a simple helper: `\My\InvalidArgumentException::assertIs($returnValue, 'string')`

Comment: Also see https://github.com/box/augmented_types

Comment: @deceze Checking input parameters introduces a whole new problem, because you need to propagate the input to the predecessor - who might expect a different type of input parameter. In Java/C# I'd tackle that be using method overloading - which (again) is not avaiable in PHP...

Comment: True, these things are not baked into the language itself; if you want those features, you'll have to replicate them in userland code. Return type hinting must be done via explicit type checking, function overloading via a `switch` statement or similar. These features can make code more concise, but their non-existence does not fundamentally impact your ability to write that same kind of functionality at all.

Comment: @deceze I fully agree with you. Nonetheless I find it quite helpful to get the opinions of other developers and get to know their way of "dealing" with the situation :)

Comment: Nothing wrong with that. My opinion: decide on how big of a problem it really is and what bad things *could* happen if you didn't check return types, then decide whether you have to or not. :)

Answer (score 0):

I would follow your approach: test the return value data type of `$this->predecessor->transform($data)` and throw an exception if it was not what it was expected to be.

I don't know whether you could be interested about [Hack programming language by Facebook](http://hacklang.org/):

> Hack is a programming language for HHVM that interoperates seamlessly
>   with PHP. Hack **reconciles the fast development cycle of PHP with the
>   discipline provided by static typing**, while adding many features
>   commonly found in other modern programming languages.